Weird Character is not showing in UTF-8
in my input xml name having the weird character which xml having utf-8
Input Feed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>JOHN�� STEPHEN</name> 

When I'm converting the xslt transform also it's not showing any error and converting well. But I need to find this weird character before the conversion or while converting in XSLT. Please suggest some methods to find this kind of weird character.

Oxygen has a hex viewer, no? And you might also want to check whether it is a font problem.

@MartinHonnen There is no font for that characters, seems like namespaces between the name changing into like that weird character

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)  says "U+FFFD � REPLACEMENT CHARACTER used to replace an unknown, unrecognised, or unrepresentable character".

@MartinHonnen is there any possibility to find this kind of character in xsl conversion

In XSLT 2.0 you can use <xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(name)"/> to identify the unknown characters. Or simply open the source in a text editor and look at the hex codes.

You can certainly simply (as long as the editor software supports it) check e.g. <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string">�</xsl:param><xsl:template match="name[contains(., $str)]"><found>{$str}</found><xsl:next-match/></xsl:template>, the real question is at what point that replacement char was put in there for which kind of character(s). But in the end it is just another Unicode character that you can check for with string functions.

If you simply want your XSLT to remove this � character you can use the translate function to convert occurrences of it to an empty string, e.g. you might use a template like this to purify text nodes:
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '�')]">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '�', '')"/>
</xsl:template>

I would guess that the � characters are being inserted by some process upstream of your XSLT which is converting data from some other source, and which has received character data as input which it isn't able to understand, either because the data was encoded using a different text encoding to what the process thought, or because the data contained some character which was not valid in XML (there are many Unicode characters which aren't allowed in XML 1.0, and a few that aren't allowed in XML 1.1). It could be worth chasing this particular name upstream to find the source of the data, and see what those characters were in the original.
